# angular date pipe affects date display

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Why is that when I display the date using the pipe date:'MM/dd/YYYY'  when the value is  2022-01-01T00:00:00 it is showing 1/01/2021 , it should be 1/01/2022 but it only occurs on this date why is that ?

As you can see the value of pharmacyRestrictionDate  is 2022-01-01T00:00:00 why is it displaying  1/01/2021 ? but when I remove the pipe the date is correct. Any idea?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlYxW.png)

#html code

```
  <div> Until {{dealData.dealTypeValues.pharmacyRestrictionDate | date:'MM/dd/YYYY'}}</div>
```

Comment: Can you show value of `dealData.dealTypeValues.pharmacyRestrictionDate` _and_ displayed output?

Comment: check the screenshot Sir

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/StVm0AO , here

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Until {{dealData.dealTypeValues.pharmacyRestrictionDate | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}

Comment: what is the difference between YYYY and yyyy ?

Comment: It would be great if you explain the reason/difference b/w YYYY & yyyy :)

Comment: Check this url for date pipe "https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe"